# Проблема при роботе с потоками C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, wcf

Имею такую часть кода в функции

```
        CallbacksRequest req = null;
        if (!requests.ContainsKey(forCity))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not сontains {0}", forCity.City);
            req = new CallbacksRequest() { forCity = forCity };
            req.callbackProcesses.Add(OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IWeatherCallback>());

            requests.Add(forCity, req);

            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckUpdate(forCity)));
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Contains {0}", forCity.City);
        req = (CallbacksRequest)requests[forCity];
```

Проблема в том, что если requests не имеет ключ forCity, то выполняется всё что в if-е и не идет дальше. Хотя там запуск нового потока происходит как фоновый.

## В чем может быть проблема?

Насколько я понимаю фоновый поток не должен останавливать основной. Может проблема в том что в фоновом потоке в функции CheckUpdate(forCity) используется бесконечный цикл. Или может проблема в том что это WCF.

Comment: кто такой **requests**??

Comment: @VardanVardanyan **requests - Hashtable**, но это не имеет значения. Проблема именно в потоках

Comment: вопросе добавьте код функции `CheckUpdate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша функция `CheckUpdate` отрабатывает в основном потоке, а не в фоновом.

Вот такой код:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckUpdate(forCity)));
```

равносилен следующему:

```
var r = CheckUpdate(forCity);
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(r));
```

То есть второй поток будет создаваться лишь тогда, когда функция `CheckUpdate` завершит свою работу.

Если вы хотите запустить функцию в фоновом потоке, а не в основном, вам нужна лямбда:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => CheckUpdate(forCity));
```

---

P. S.: Интересно, что за тип возвращает `CheckUpdate`, чтобы первоначальный код скомпилировался?

Comment: тип ThreadStart, как раз в этом и была проблема

Comment: Thread t = new Thread(CheckUpdate);
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start(forCity);

Answer (score 1):

> CheckUpdate(forCity) используется бесконечный цикл

Если у вас работает бесконечный цикл ну конечно же эта функция не пойдет дальше.При исползования делегата `ThreadStart` в  программе будут работать одновременно главный поток, и второй поток. Кроме действий по созданию второго потока, в главном потоке также производятся некоторые действия в фунцкии `CheckUpdate`. Как только все потоки отработают, программа завершит свое выполнение. 
У вас главный поток в последнем строке оператора `if`,будет ждать завершении второго потока, и поскольку оно не завершится то ваша функция не будет идти дальше.